# @RequestParam defaultValue overrides user input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the @RequestParam I need help with.

```
@RequestParam(name = "findBy", required = false, defaultValue = "id") String findBy
```

The defaultValue is always "id" even if the user input is different, i.e:

```
/api?findBy=userName
```

I need the defaultValue to overrides only when the user doesn't do any input.

Thanks your help.
Edit------------------------------
Sorry for not include the complete controller before.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PostsController {

    @Autowired
    FindService findService = new FindService();

    @GetMapping
    public Object getPosts(@RequestParam(name = "findBy", required = false, defaultValue = "id") String findBy,
                           @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = "userName") String sortBy,
                           @RequestParam(name = "tags") String... tags) {

        System.out.println("Inside FindController, findBy: " + findBy);
        System.out.println("Inside FindController, sortBy: " + sortBy);

        return findService.getPostsList(findBy, sortBy, tags);
    }
}
```

I had problems with my findService.getPostsList return so I set some prints inside the controller in order to confirm the findBy and sortBy params values and I found they always were the defaultValue even if I try any other input.

Thanks again for your help.

Edit-------------
Ok the problem was always on my side. Have been trying the petitions without the "&" that separes the params. Thanks your answers. It really helped me to realize where the issue was.

```
wrong:
http://localhost:8080/api?findBy=username?sortBy=lastname
```

```
right:
http://localhost:8080/api?findBy=username&sortBy=lastname
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete Controller method?

Comment: that would never happpen and likely means there is some error in the way you call the endpoint. Complete controller method would be helpful

Comment: As I can see, your method and Request Param configuration is correct, and will set the `findBy=id` when no value is passing for the findBy with the URL(like this `<APP URL>/api` or `<APP URL>/api/findBy=`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
@GetMapping(path="/api")
public String findBy(@RequestParam(name = "findBy", required = false, defaultValue = "id") String findBy){
    return findBy;
}
```

API call and response with override

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/api?findBy=username'
username
```

API call and response with default

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/api?findBy='
id
```